# What is the best method to cache rest api requests for multiple users in a dashboard?

Tags: javascript, php, rest, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

our company currently has multiple stores running on Woocommerce. We use the rest api to connect to each store to get updates like number of items sold on a particular day or total income etc. The problem I have is we have several users looking at this data and at the moment all the requests to each website happen every 5sec and run in JavaScript from the client. When I have 20 people looking at the “dashboard” at once that is a lot of requests to the servers.

What would be the best way to make a middle man/server than would essentially get the information and store it that my team could then connect to so they are hitting this middle server not our stores servers every 5 sec each?

Many thanks for advice.

Comment: Hello and welcome! A 5 seconds interval is imo very extreme - if you raise that to 1 min and cache the results in the meantime in browser you wouldn't need a middleware. On the other hand, if the information NEEDS to be that accurate, a middleware wouldn't solve it because you will only export the data every X min to the middleware. So, a 5 second interval wouldn't make any sense there neither.

Comment: Have you tried [WP REST Cache Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-cache/)?